# Is it possible to remove from an indexed data structure and avoid shifting at the same time?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have:

```
0 => a
1 => x
2 => A
...
1356 => w
1357 => o
```

As of it is now, i can easily get pos 555 because it is indexed, in other words, no linear search is required.

Now if I remove position 333, everything above it will have to be shifted because next time I call `get(555)` the element removed will be the old 556 which is now the new 555 after the shift.

But shifting is expensive when your list is large.

Is there a way to remove without shifting and still keep everything correctly indexed?

The first thing that comes to mind is a doubled-linked-list, but it is not indexed.

Do I need some weird combination of data structures here to save on shifting and still have indexes?

Comment: What all do you need to the data structure to be able to do? A simple approach allows for O(sqrt(N)) performance (break the size N array into k arrays of at most k elements), though using balanced binary trees (along the lines of a segment tree) allow for O(log N) performance but is somewhat more complicated.

Comment: That's interesting. Can you elaborate on the breaking into multiple arrays method in an answer? Thanks!

Comment: The `TreeMap` does not satisfy your needs?

Comment: It might be better to think of it as k rows, each a linked list with at most k columns, where k is O(sqrt(N)). You then just have to ensure the linked lists stay O(sqrt(N)) in size and maintain the index number of the first (and perhaps last) element. With 16 elements you would have something like this: ((0,3),(4,7),(8,11),(12,15)). If you wanted say element 9, well 9 is in the interval (8,11) (found via binary search), zero-indexed row 2, and that it is the second element in row 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually support random access and shifts in time O(log n) each using a modified binary tree called an order statistics tree. This is a balanced binary tree (say, a tree that's balanced as if it were a red/black tree or AVL tree even though the elements aren't sorted) in which each node stores the number of nodes in its left and right subtrees. Using a modified BST lookup algorithm, it's possible to find the kth element in the tree in time O(log n). Once you've got that node, you can then delete it in time O(log n), or insert a node right before it or right after it in time O(log n).

Many introductory algorithms textbooks, such as CLRS, describe how to make these operations work in detail.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there such implementation in Java? The data structure that I want is very simple in terms of its external API, but the internal details you describe sounds complicated. Therefore an implementation somewhere would be of great help!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this isn't in the standard Java APIs. I don't know of any Java implementations off the top of my head, though I'd probably start by Googling for it. Hope you find something!